# PHP fpassthru - How to output the file data without printing it on screen?

Tags: php, fopen

How can I output the file data without printing it on screen?

```
$file = "G:/...7F0D23C62002546097485FC518222504D29693FC8D2FCBB7.tgz";

// Open the file in a binary mode
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

// Dump the tar and stop the script
$success = fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);

if(!$success) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to downlonad');
} else {
   echo 'success!';
}
```

Result,

> ��m�U�Vmo�6�O��\%��W�&0Xۤmծ�aZ&�'�^C����1$m��ꮪ���O>`��>�c;;U�km��G���`A0>C���LhH�&�`���w��#�W�lv�ZUl��~_��ŝg�^{Ww�0�+��%J�/A�!��AD��8"�P��3�K�D�$  �K�V;�����,Uf{Өn��6EW�}�ԧϭ�@g����������X?aI�$¶��1��s&3�8%���#�S�/:�z
>   �80������s��Je��撟O�*�O`*.@
>   �5^.{,v��.*�[�����iZ���4e1.u�Pm�\��MU˅�Bf��Y.�f���k>���C���z�И]i�ت)}i�^��JYz֪2z�=����l��^w��|�*���^'�}亩V�;6y*``��]A��  ����*ߗ�6_w���Mg�#��
>   �����۟0W��w���v�L����4�DS)b�""�3F9��h��
>   ƶ&t%���i�,*��?��a�i,m��e��̗���䒢Dʄeh*�ǒ=W��Q�d<)i{��%�X�QEO�:ƛm��o�J��P�'noKS�T���U&?q�u�+��V��FM;m��j-��ih�1�l;��N�o�Ԏ�t=��l��>G�[Cݬ��'d�����0�!3��s�P�dI�S�RI1�����O�7V,�|�%$~Lx6�g"LJRNq"� i
>   ��18�mL(G0�����8�%a��cȌ���kB/�}����,G���C   'q�x!X\�"A!C��H_H)p�+�g��ٷ�����*������ޫA�6�G�
>   6p���d�$*m�;�7�U,l��T��������~�v|P~Q��E��T'�����
>   ��qb$##����/)�h%
>   ?��1�Q�Ә>�kB?#h"�Q<    9�p�$���O|8�"FI,�L��?���&�����[��k�5gB������&}�^-��~��^�Ms;��p�����r�f�__��?����:#��3��Z=�!s{X���[��.pA�h�Tƌ��˺�v��'}�7���֫�qd)ӝ��t����7�����(success!

But I just want

> success!

Is it possible?

Comment: I know that and have read it through!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but maybe the answer is usefull for somebody.

```
ob_start();
var_dump(fpassthru($fp));

$success = ob_get_clean();
```

... then check the $success  for "success!" text.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the tar file to download by setting the appropriate headers:

```
$file = "./test.tgz";

// Set headers
header("Content-Type: application/x-tar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.tgz");
header("Content-Length: " + filesize($file));    
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

// Open the file in a binary mode
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

// Dump the tar and stop the script
$success = fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);
```

PHP header() function documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score -1):

The `fpassthru()` function reads all data from the current position in an open file, until EOF, and writes the result to the output buffer.

This function returns the number of characters passed or `FALSE` on failure.

[PHP `fpassthru()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fpassthru.asp)

### Tips and Notes

> **Note:** When using [fpassthru()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fpassthru.asp) on a binary file on Windows, remember to open the file in binary mode.
>
> **Tip:** Call [rewind()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_rewind.asp) to set the file pointer to the beginning of the file if you have already written to the file.
>
> **Tip:** If you just want to dump the contents of a file to the output buffer, without first modifying it, use the [readfile()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_readfile.asp) function instead.

Comment: `writes the result to the output buffer` - what does it mean?